# gem customizations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, geokit

I added some caching functionality to the geokit gem and used gemcutter to create a copy 'badnaam-geokit'. The only changed are in Geocoders.rb which works fine if I just modify it locally.

However, after I published it to rubygems and installed it and require it as 'badnaam-geokit' in my environment.rb (config.gem "badnaam-geokit") file I get a nasty.

Any ideas?

Here is the my fork on github

http://github.com/badnaam/geokit-gem

and here is the gem.
http://rubygems.org/gems/badnaam-geokit

```
no such file to load -- badnaam-geokit
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the :lib option.

So this is what worked

config.gem "badnaam-geokit", :lib => "geokit"

Comment: You answer was posted after the answer from @wuputah, you should probably delete your answer and accepts his answer.

Answer (score 1):

While your gem has changed names, the library name has not changed. Your `config.gem` line is telling Rails to load the gem and then `require 'badnaam-geokit'` but there's no file in your gem by that name.

The fix this, use the `:lib` option to `config.gem`:

```
config.gem 'badnaam-geokit', :lib => 'geokit'
```

Furthermore, pushing gems to Rubygems for changes like this is not encouraged. I would instead suggest you switch your Rails project to [use Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) (which [works great with Rails 2.3.5](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html)) and then use the `:git` option to load the gem directly from your Github fork.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that in mind. The solution you recommend yields the same error though. I put in the :require option and it does not seem to take any effect. Do I need to have the regular geokit gem installed as well?

Comment: Whoops, `:require` is the Bundler option; `:lib` is `config.gem` option.